# Can I get a question deleted?

Tags: support

I posted [a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15901/how-can-i-give-the-player-the-impression-of-speed) a while back that was closed as an exact duplicate, which is probably fair enough. My bad.

The problem is that I tried to delete the question at the time, and I couldn't because an answer already existed.

It's not very important but people are still down-voting this question even though it's closed and I even asked for it to be closed, and I can no longer do anything about it.

So my question is, is there any way I can get this question deleted?

Comment: IMAO the Stack Exchange sites are very good to get information, but their "scoring" system is so flawed it is completely pointless to give any kind of shit about it. Just forget it and simply use the site to ask questions when you need to, or to answer them when you feel to, completely ignoring any kind of point.

Comment: @Lohoris, that sounds a bit contradictory - SO sites have very good information, **but** the scoring system is seriously flawed... Since it's the scoring (voting) system that *generates* the good information, it can't be *that* bad. :) Sure, there are flaws - but *in general, over the long-term*, people's scores have *some* correlation to how much good information they provide. I agree it's not worth worrying about, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Can I delete my post on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25088/how-can-i-delete-my-post-on-stack-overflow) - "No"

[I can't delete my Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42659/cant-delete-my-question) - "works as intended".

Sorry, but SE is designed to preserve things, and they intentionally made it hard to delete Questions that have Answers (see the links for their reasoning). You can ask a moderator to delete it, but it's not guaranteed.

I sympathize, since I've had the same problem. Also (and you didn't hear this from me :) it is *still* technically possible to turn a post Community Wiki without a mod - eight edits makes a post CW. Edits have to be five minutes apart or they are merged though. It's a lot of work, but if things ever get bad enough, it's an option... :)

Comment: However, I just upvoted your question - the +5 upvote will make up for 2.5 downvotes. :) I agree once a Question is closed, it's not nice to downvote.

Comment: And another exact duplicate that will be closed and downvoted. Woe is me. I will also add that the reason that duplicates are closed are to not have information spread around all over the place. If the answer is relevant to my duplicate, it should be relevant to the original question, in which case it should be merged. It seems really quite stupid to have this as the intended workings.

Comment: If you mean *this* question, no - the links I posted are on meta.stackoverflow. Cross-site duplicates aren't closed for duplication.

Comment: Also - and this is something everyone should know :) - votes on *meta.gamedev* don't affect your rep either way. Only votes on the main site. (Note this is different from meta.stackoverflow).

Answer (score 2):

Exact duplicates can be merged. And then the remaining stub can be deleted.